# Issue after update Flutter project to JAVA 11

Tags: java, android, flutter

After the update of my Flutter project to JAVA 11 suddenly I got this error when I try to run the app on any device.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileQa4DebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:androidJdkImage'.
   > Failed to transform core-for-system-modules.jar to match attributes {artifactType=_internal_android_jdk_image, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for JdkImageTransform: /Users/enzoftware/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-30/core-for-system-modules.jar.
         > jlink executable /Applications/Android Studio Preview.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/jlink does not exist.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 56s
Exception: Gradle task assembleQa4Debug failed with exit code 1
```

I tried doing `flutter clean`, install again the SDK for API 30 and reinstalling everything from scratch but the problem persist.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Change version of JAVA 8 because JAVA 11 isn't good for using Flutter. I was on sam

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).